# Error when trying to put log into s3 bucket on AWS EMR using spark submit

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark

Hi Iam getting the error when Iam trying to upload the log file to s3 when running on EMR using spark-submit.

/tmp/log4j-application.log is the file giving in the log4j properties.

Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to calculate MD5 hash: /tmp/log4j-application.log

Answer (score 0):

with a .log suffix, it's more likely to be the log file itself. In which case spark-submit is failing because the file is growing during the submit, and the checksum isn't stable.

Look closely at the file. If it is the log: don't submit. If it is a log .properties file, possibly something else...file a spark JIRA, with the full stack trace, and without your AWS secrets.
But be confident it is the properties first.